# Socket.io send message to all active connection on specific time

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to broadcast message to all the active connections on specific time. Let's say broadcast message to all active users on 9th September 2015, 17:00:00

I can convert the date to UNIX timestamp and use the settimeout function for this. Is there any other way to do so.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    io.emit('this', 'Broadcast message');   //broadcast message- will be sent to all active session
},60000000);
```

Is there any other way to do the same??

Comment: yes you can use cron , https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: Thanks Osman. will look into it and update